# How to initiate controller/action in CFWheels, for Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, cfwheels

I have been trying to get cfwheels to work with FineUploader for two days now, and I just can't figure out how to force the jQuery script to execute a Controller/Action. This is how far I've come so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var restricteduploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        // Since we're using jQuery, use the jQuery way to select the HTML element
        element: $('##restricted-fine-uploader')[0],
        request: {
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr("href") + "/index.cfm?controller=users&action=UploadFileXhr&format=json", // References "/say/hello?format=json"
            dataType: "json",
            endpoint: '/index.cfm?controller=users&action=UploadFileXhr&format=json'
        },
        multiple: false,
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'txt'],
            sizeLimit: 5120000000 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
        },
        text: {
            uploadButton: 'Click or Drop'
        },
        showMessage: function(message) {
            // Using Twitter Bootstrap's classes and jQuery selector and method
            $('##restricted-fine-uploader').append('<div class="alert alert-error">' + message + '</div>');
        },
        debug: true
    });
});
```

The CFWheels documentation says I have to use this to get an asynchronous request:

```
(function($){$(document).ready(function(){

    // Listen to the "click" event of the "alert-button" link and make an AJAX request
    $("#alert-button").click(function() {
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: $(this).attr("href") + "?format=json", // References "/say/hello?format=json"
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(response) {
     $("h1").html(response.message);
     $("p").html(response.time);
     }
     });
     return false; // keeps the normal request from firing
    });

});})(jQuery);
```

These three lines is what I'm trying to incorporate into my code (because that's what I think I need):

**type: "POST",**

**url: $(this).attr("href") + "?format=json", // References "/say/hello?format=json"**

**dataType: "json",**

But everything I've tried has not worked. I can't even work on my actual upload code to get that to work, since I can't even get the uploader to initiate the required controller/action.

Hopefully someone will be able to point me in the right direction. Thank you!

**Question also posted to cfWheels mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cfwheels/UKk_57y9ncQ**

Comment: _"But everything I've tried has not worked"_ - error: "not worked" is undefined.

Comment: Well those 3 lines I mentioned, I tried taking them out of the request bracket and just putting them in on their own. I tried commenting out endpoint and just leaving those 3 lines in there, that also didn't work, because endpoint was still included (by default) and set to server/upload, which didn't work for my case. I tried putting the 3 lines before endpoint, after, inside and still nothing.

Comment: The way it is now, in my FireBug I get this: http://localhost:8500/mywheelssite/index.cfm?controller=users&action=UploadFileXhr&format=json&qquuid=bf5362e9-9371-4023-82f7-45a0e9888249&qqtotalfilesize=521148&qqfile=SportIcons_000019009810.jpg as the "POST" but it's still failing. I also tried making my upload action just "redirectTo(route="home"); abort;" to just see if it will fire and exclude the action as being the problem, and it never did.

Comment: It still seems like you're not entirely describing what is wrong - you need to provide the error message and/or say "I expected X but received Y". What you're saying might make more sense to people familiar with cfWheels/FineUploader, but it appears to be only half the story. [Edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14567658/edit) to properly include the details you've provided in your comments - i.e. include the full URL you're getting in FireBug and point out whether the URL looks correct but is behaving wrong, or if it has the wrong query_string, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with FineUploader, but normally when I am doing AJAX requests in Wheels, I use the urlFor() function to build the correct controller/action location.

[CFWheels - urlFor](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/function/urlfor)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what problem you're facing. Follow these steps:

1. Make sure in your controller `Say.cfc` provides the JSON format to the Ajax call:
   In the `init()` function of `Say.cfc`, make sure to add this:

   ```
   <cffunction name="init" hint="It secures component from invalid access">
       <!--- this is necessary --->
       <cfset provides("json") />
   </cffunction>
   ```
2. Now, in the `hello` action, render the data you want to provide without layout. Remove any `<cfabort>` tags present inside the action:

   ```
   <!--- this will go at the very end of the action --->
   <!--- here the attribute data is the data you want to serve: a query, struct or any other custom data generated inside a `<cfsavecontent>`  ---> 
   <cfset renderWith(data=data,layout=false) />
   ```

I hope this works for you.